# Date.parse() vs moment().unix()

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

There seams to be a significant difference in the amount of milliseconds I am getting when comparing the results from `Date.parse()` and `moment().unix()`. Not sure what I am missing as both `.parse()` and `.unix()` are meant to return the date/time string in milliseconds.

**Example:**

```
const endDate = '2019-05-29 17:00:00';

console.log("Moment: ", moment(endDate).unix()); // 1559142000
console.log("Parse: ", Date.parse(new Date(endDate))); // 1559142000000
```

Comment: they would take a different amount of time ot execute, there is no way to run them at exactly the same time...in your code Date.Parse() runs after moment.unix() is already done...

Comment: `Date.parse(new Date(endDate)))` requires parsing the date twice. `Date.parse(endDate))` will give identical results and parse once. Safari will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment(endDate).unix()` returns unix time, seconds since Jan 1. 1970.

`Date.parse(new Date(endDate))` returns milliseconds since Jan 1. 1970, or 1000 times unix time. `Date.parse(new Date(endDate))/1000` is unix time

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in second

check out the [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method on Date

Comment: Unfortunatly i belive `.getTime()` has spotty browser support and even with babel, i am having issues in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

"It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970,[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)". [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

The amount returned by moment's `unix()` function is the seconds since this.

`Date.parse()` will returns the amount of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)